# For Loop : number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Tags: r

I am working on an R Markdown document using a DICE (climate-economy) model.

I have a function YPC that depends on two variables tt and r. My goal is to obtain a data frame that contains all possible images of YPC (for all possible values of r and tt), with the cell YPC[i,j] containing the value of YPC for i=tt and j=r. For each line of my matrix (each value of tt), I want every cell after a certain value r=l[tt] to be filled with the value 0.

Example : l[1]=100 ; Then all the cells on the first line after the 100th column should be filled with zero.

I create my matrix and define its cells as follows

```
YPC<-matrix(nrow = NT, ncol = l[100])
for (i in 1:NT){
for (j in 1:l[100]) {
        if (j<=l[i]) {
    YPC[i,j] <- fYPC(Y, r=j, tt=i)}
    else{
       YPC[i,j] <- 0}
  }
}
```

When I print the generated cells, I see that it works great up to the l[i] value. At the l[i] value, it prints "Inf" and a warning message : number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length. At the end of the computation, I obtain a "no loop for break/next, jumping to top level" error.

I don't write all my code here as it is quite long and only few elements seem relevant.

Also, a reproducible example is hard to provide as I don't use a regular dataset here. I only have simple data for parameters of the model that my code builds on to create several equations that use those parameters.

EDIT

Thanks for your answers.

Here is how fYPC is defined :

```
fYPC <- function(Y, r, tt=NULL){
 if (is.null(tt)){
    output=(exp(Y/l+et2*sqrt(2)*erfinv(2*r/l-1))+exp(Y/l+et2*sqrt(2)*erfinv(2(r-1)/l-1)))
  }else {
    output=(exp(Y[tt]/l[tt]+et2*sqrt(2)*erfinv(2*r/l[tt]-1))+exp(Y[tt]/l[tt]+et2*sqrt(2)*erfinv(2*(r-1)/l[tt]-1)))
  }
return(output)
}
```

In the is.null part, Y is a value so the output is also of length 1.

In the else part, Y is a vector, then Y[tt] and l[tt] are length 1 and so is the final output 
About NT, you can actually replace it by 100. And l[i] is defined as follows (with pop0, popasym, popadj respectively 100, 1000, 0.134)  :

```
l = pop0 
for(i in 2:NT) l[i] <- l[i-1] * (popasym / l[i-1])**popadj
```

Comment: Hi Baptiste and welcome to SO. I tried to reproduce your error by setting: `NT <- 50` and `l <- 1:100`. Since I don't know yur function `fYPC()` I replaced it simply by `1`. In this case no error occured. Can you give further information about the return of `fYPC()` and the structur of `NT` and `l`?

Comment: 'At the end of the computation, I obtain a "no loop for break/next, jumping to top level" error.' This sounds like an internal error of the function fYPC. Perhaps you should do `debug(fYPC)` and see what's happening inside. Also, I didn't understand when the loop breaks.

Comment: The warning that you get is the same as if you do `x = matrix(1:4, ncol=2);
x[1,2] = 1:2`, that is trying to put an element of length >1 into a slot of the matrix. Is it possible that your function in `YPC[i,j] <- fYPC(Y, r=j, tt=i)` returns an element of length >1?

Comment: I edited it. From what I understand, the loop should break once it has computed the cells for all i and j between the written values. There is no "end" command needed here, right ?